# JSON encode in PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I wanted this type of json using php and mysql. I tried a lot but the json which I get are duplicate data and very complex.

JSON I need:

```
{"data":[
    {"Maharashtra":[
        {"Mumbai":[
            {"place_name":"Gateway of India"},
            {"place_name":"Marine Lines"},
            {"place_name":"Juhu"}
            ]},
        {"Pune":[
            {"place_name":"Singhad"},
            ]}
        }],
    {"Goa":[
        {"Panji":[
            {"place_name":"panji"}  
        ]}
    ]}
}]}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
require('database.php'); 

$counter=0; 
$state = "SELECT distinct(s.state_name)
               , ac.city_name 
          FROM all_state s, all_city ac 
          WHERE s.s_id = ac.state_id;"; 

$resultState = $conn->query($state);
$return_arr['data'] = array(); 

while($row = $resultState->fetch_assoc()){
   $getStateName = $row['state_name']; 
   $getCityName = $row['city_name']; 
   $state_array[$getStateName] = array($getCityName);      

   array_push($return_arr['data'], $state_array); 
} 

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: You want to create a json or read values from json ? Please explain clearly

Comment: How does this relate to PHP & MySQL ? I don't see PHP codes nor SQL statements...

Comment: show me your efforts, also show me your input,

Comment: I want to create JSON,
following is my code
<?php
require('database.php');

 $counter=0;
  $state = "SELECT distinct(s.state_name),ac.city_name FROM all_state s, all_city ac where s.s_id = ac.state_id;";

  $resultState   = $conn -> query($state);
  $return_arr['data']    =  array();
  while($row = $resultState -> fetch_assoc() ){

   $getStateName = $row['state_name'];
   $getCityName  = $row['city_name'];
   $state_array[$getStateName] = array($getCityName);
   

      array_push($return_arr['data'],$state_array);
    
  }

   echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>

Comment: The question closes as Unclear or lacking MCVE. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

your query only returns states and cities so data like:

```
{"place_name":"Gateway of India"},
{"place_name":"Marine Lines"},
{"place_name":"Juhu"}
```

is not there: to push the data you are getting in to propper array use this:

```
while($row = $resultState->fetch_assoc()){
    $stateArray[$row['state']][$row['city']] = array(); // the empty array is there to push your remaining data in to
}
$result = array('data' => $stateArray);
echo json_encode($result);
```

UPDATE TO ANSWER COMMENT:

You can add details to your array like this (or any other way, there are many, this is the most basic):

```
$stateArray[$stateYouWant][$cityYouWant]['place_names'] = array('Gateway of India', 'Marine Lines', 'Juhu');
```

This will give ytou something like:

```
{"Maharashtra":[
    {"Mumbai":[
        {"place_names":[  
            "Gateway of India",
            "Marine Lines",
            "Juhu"]}
        ]},
```

The variation you want:

```
{"Mumbai":[
        {"place_name":"Gateway of India"},
        {"place_name":"Marine Lines"},
        {"place_name":"Juhu"}
        ]},
```

Is not possible because json is actually a string representation of associative array (or JS object) and that means you can not have same name keys on the same array level.

Comment: I want to print details inside of city array.. how to do it?
{"place_name":"Gateway of India"},
{"place_name":"Marine Lines"},
{"place_name":"Juhu"}

Comment: I am getting error on ['place_names']- Error is Illegal string offset 'place_names'

Comment: ofc you are getting the error, because you are not creating that offset, your mysql query does not return that data